# Am i wrong in how i use Relu as hypertan seams better?

Tags: c#, neural-network

well i made a neural network back propagation network in which.
The network makes use of a hypertan evaluation like so:

```
private static double HyperTanFunction(double x)
{
    if (x < -20.0) return -1.0; 
    else if (x > 20.0) return 1.0;
    else return Math.Tanh(x);
}
```

As is used in :

```
private double[] ComputeOutputs(double[] xValues)
{
    double[] hSums = new double[numHidden]; // hidden nodes sums scratch array
    double[] oSums = new double[numOutput]; // output nodes sums

    for (int i = 0; i < xValues.Length; ++i) // copy x-values to inputs
            this.inputs[i] = xValues[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < numHidden; ++j)  // compute i-h sum of weights * inputs
        for (int i = 0; i < numInput; ++i)
            hSums[j] += this.inputs[i] * this.ihWeights[i][j]; // note +=

    for (int i = 0; i < numHidden; ++i)  // add biases to input-to-hidden sums
        hSums[i] += this.hBiases[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < numHidden; ++i)   // apply activation
        this.hOutputs[i] = HyperTanFunction(hSums[i]); // hard-coded

    for (int j = 0; j < numOutput; ++j)   // compute h-o sum of weights * hOutputs
        for (int i = 0; i < numHidden; ++i)
            oSums[j] += hOutputs[i] * hoWeights[i][j];

    for (int i = 0; i < numOutput; ++i)  // add biases to input-to-hidden sums
        oSums[i] += oBiases[i];

    double[] softOut = Softmax(oSums); // softmax activation does all outputs at once for efficiency

    Array.Copy(softOut, this.outputs, softOut.Length);

    double[] retResult = new double[numOutput]; // could define a GetOutputs method instead
    Array.Copy(this.outputs, retResult, retResult.Length);
    return retResult;
}
```

I am reading a lot about neural networks, but its a complex subject.
In search for better network and data validation.
I was reading about anova data validation, then I stumbled into Leaky Relu.
Its said to be better then sigmoid or hyperTan.

So instead of using hypertan, i replaced the code inside that function for

```
 if (x < 0.0) return 0.01 * x; else return x;  // Leaky Relu
```

At first i was a bit surprised that without altering anything else, it worked for a single hidden layer. But later i noticed, that hypertan seams to resolve better (higher precision in end result). And that made me wonder (as these days people seam to favor Relu over other methods), when using Relu should my ComputeOutputs function also be adjusted ?.

Comment: What do you mean by adjusted? on what kind of task did you compare these two activation functions (classification or regression?)

Comment: Are you asking why Relu didn't work better than Tanh in your particular task?

Comment: just common clasification over a dataset, i wonder if i perhaps didnt corectly implement leaky Relu

Comment: no your implementation is correct. And back to your question, there is no guarantee or what so ever that Relu works better than Tanh in all applications. In fact there is a theorem guaranteeing that something like this will never happen, i.e., there is no activation function in the whole universe that works better than others in ALL applications.